# TypeError: Buffer is not a constructor using Angular Material Table Exporter

Tags: angular, angular-material, exporter

The error I got from console (firefox)

[image]

I want to be able to export my table (Material tables) of my angular app using mat-table-exporter: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mat-table-exporter.

This is the stack I am trying to reproduce : https://stackblitz.com/edit/mte-demo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

My HTML template :

```
<button mat-raised-button (click)="exporter.exportTable('xlsx', {fileName:'test', sheet: 'sheet_name', Props: {Author: 'Talha'}})">Excel</button>
<table mat-table [dataSource]="serverArray" multiTemplateDataRows matTableExporter #exporter="matTableExporter">
   .
   .
   .
</table>
```

my package.json

```
{
  "name": "...",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@amcharts/amcharts4": "4.4.2",
    "@amcharts/amcharts4-geodata": "^4.0.21",
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^6.0.0-beta.18",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "^8.2.14",
    "@types/paho-mqtt": "^1.0.4",
    "@types/zen-observable": "^0.5.4",
    "angular5-social-login": "^1.0.9",
    "aws-amplify": "^1.1.19",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.401.0",
    "core-js": "^2.6.4",
    "d3": "^5.9.1",
    "expo": "^31.0.6",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "mat-table-exporter": "^1.2.5",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ngx-facebook": "^2.4.0",
    "ngx-tour-core": "^4.0.1",
    "ngx-tour-md-menu": "^4.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.19",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.22",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "^8.2.14",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.16",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.6",
    "@types/node": "^10.12.26",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^2.0.5",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.4.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3",
    "webpack": "4.41.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There was a script in my index.html file :

```
<script>
    var global = global || window;
    // var Buffer = Buffer || [];
    var process = process || {
      env: { DEBUG: undefined },
      version: []
    };
</script>
```

Commenting the line with the "Buffer" variable fixed my problem.